# How to make a custom Flash Player?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, avm2

I am currently working on a project of creating my own Flash Player to which I could implement my own custom handling and execution of SWF files that are being played in the browser. Unfortunately, the two major ones, Adobe Flash Player and Chrome's Pepper Flash are both closed source and thus I can't directly create my own versions of these. Can I however, somehow modify these, or what would be the best alternatives I could look at, that can play most flash content?

Comment: Did you see https://github.com/mozilla/shumway ?

Comment: Haven't seen that one, thanks I will check it out!

Comment: Look also for : `SWF Format Specifications` (is a PDF)...

Comment: @VC.One OP needs a ready solution it seems, not a blank start.

Comment: Yes that's right, I would rather not have to write one completely from scratch.

Comment: On a related note is there anyway at all too just vote to cancel adobe's call to discontinue flashplayer? Or will it come down to some AIR dev making a browser that calls on AIR To play swfs?

Comment: @quantomworks The problem with Flash Player that it has nothing to offer us, not any longer. 15 years ago it was an amazing tool for lightweight apps and animations and video streaming, 10 years ago new fast AS3 kicked in, and Flex for front-end business applications, but now... Several security scandals over these years, GPU support that cannot be used as is and needs Starling or such, even mobile development, though possible, still requires third-party ANEs to support **basic** things like in-apps, auth and ads.

Comment: @quantomworks I'd also like to add that it not only has nothing to offer us anymore, it puts a great risk on your clients (and yourself) because of the numerous security issues and vulnerabilities it introduces (seemingly with every release). I don't see any reason why you would want Adobe to continue supporting it, other than preference for AS3 I suppose, which isn't a good reason (I like it as well though). Not to mention the additional step of installing the damn thing, [which is a security issue in itself.](https://www.google.com/search?q=infected+flash+installer)

Comment: @DodgerThud Don't you understand that all languages have their potential exploits and vulnerabilities? JavaScript is one of the main attack vectors in techniques such as cross-site scripting (XSS) and cross-site request forgery (CSRF) because it's rather easy to write for the web. Native exploits exist as well and were even responsible for the recent WannaCry attack. Everyone just targets flash target when in reality all languages are just as dangerous. If you see Symantec's exploit list. You'll see Flash as well as many many other applications that have to be constantly patched.

Comment: @Organis I do see your point on the ANE side. Though this is in reguards to flash. ANE are through AIR And AIR is still going to live according to Adobe.

Comment: And by you @DodgerThud I meant everyone... But I mean honestly. For every Adobe Flash record there's an Internet Explorer record. https://www.symantec.com/security_response/landing/vulnerabilities.jsp . I don't understand. People just knocked on it as hard as they did Norton back in the day. I think it's just a bandwagon. Just as said in this post here: https://www.newgrounds.com/bbs/topic/1424896/1

Comment: Languages don't matter (that much), I'm talking about the context they're running in. The flash player. If you have to compare the flash player to Internet explorer, then you're already fighting a losing battle. Tom Fulp can post as many rants as he wants and declare facts as memes, it won't help Flash. I respect your opinion on the subject though, and I apologize if my comments come off as harsh. I'll let the subject rest here as well though, because it's sort of off topic to the question.